# widgets not working

Tags: functions, widgets, register-sidebar

I pasted my siderbar widget code in `widgets.php` file

```
    function right_sidebar_widget() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Right Siderbar',
        'id' => 'right-siderbar',
        'description' => 'Right Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'right_sidebar_widget' );
```

included `widgets.php` file to `functions.php` file using

`include_once 'includes/widgets.php';`

But widgets not working, I got the error

> The theme you are currently using isn’t widget-aware, meaning that it
>   has no sidebars that you are able to change. For information on making
>   your theme widget-aware, please follow these instructions.

Note: I checked, the above code working when in the functions.php and also widgets.php included successfully

Comment: If that piece of code is working in functions.php and widgets.php is correctly loaded with the same code but not wrking, there is nothing we can do. Something else must be happening that you have not noted and we can not know if we don't take a closer look to your code and files. Are you sure the code is working when you write it in functions.php? Does your theme have any sidebar.php file or use `dynamic_sidebar( some where??

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'right_sidebar_widget' );
```

with

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'right_sidebar_widget' );
```

Comment: also tried, got same error

Comment: Make sure- `widgets.php` file is included correctly. Try using the code directly in `functions.php` file and see what happens.

Comment: code working in function.php and i also checked widgets.php included correctly

Comment: That's strange! The code seems like your `widgets.php` file is in a directory named `includes`. Recheck it.